# Weird artifact on Landsat 8 image downloaded from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I am trying to download images from google earth engine for the Netherlands from 2013 through 2021. For the years 2013, 2017, and 2019, the images I'm getting have a weird white artifact on them, as shown below:[image: weird landsat artifact]

This is not happening for other years. 2014, 2015, 2016, 2018, 2020, and 2021 are all completely fine.

The code I am using is given below:

```js
// Landsat8 has 11 bands, defined here
var landsat_8_bands = ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B9','B10','B11'];

// This is the string we need to pass to fetch Tier 1 images from Landsat8 Collection 1
// All images after december 31 2021 are in collection 2
// Collection 1 data will be maintained in the Earth Engine Data Catalog at least through 2022
var landsat8 = 'LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA';

// Max. acceptable cloud cover is 10%
var allowed_cloud_cover = 10;

// Country we want data for
var region = Netherlands;

// Define the name of the region as a string; this can be passed to functions later
var region_string = 'Netherlands';

// Year we are downloading images for
var year = 2019; 

Map.addLayer(Netherlands, {color: 'blue'}, 'NL shapefile')

// Crop function for cropping our region of interest (Netherlands)
function crop_aoi(image){
  return image.clip(region);
}

// Map the function to one year of Landsat8 ShapefileTOA data and take the median value of each pixel in that image
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(landsat8)
                  .map(crop_aoi)
                  .select(landsat_8_bands) // this is to ensure that only the 11 landsat8 bands are fetched
                  .filterDate(year + '-03-01', year + '-09-30') // take images between march and september
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', allowed_cloud_cover));
  //                .median();
var composite = collection.median();
composite = composite.float();

print('All band names', composite.bandNames());
// print(composite);

Export.image.toDrive({image: composite,
                      description: 'landsat8_' + year + '_' + region_string,
                      folder: 'Masters_thesis',
                      fileNamePrefix: 'landsat8_28992_' + year + '_' + region_string,
                      region: region,
                      maxPixels: 10e11,
                      scale: 30
                      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see slightly diagonal stripes or boundaries in your composite image, they're likely to be borders between different source images — the angle of the stripe is the satellite's orbital path. In this case, there is simply no image for that location and date range **with low enough cloud cover.** Thus, there is no data — it is not white but rather masked.

If I run your code with the `allowed_cloud_cover` set to 15 instead of 10, I can see the stripe filled in with a noticeably cloudy image — there are only 3 images in that area, with CLOUD_COVER values of 12 to 14.6, so there isn't enough non-cloudy data for it to consistently dominate the median.

[image]

You should consider setting `allowed_cloud_cover` even higher — from experimentation, it seems that the additional non-cloudy data that is thus included is more helpful than the additional clouds are harmful.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful!

Comment: I downloaded with a higher `allowed_cloud_cover` setting, and it did clear things up. But for some reason, there is a portion of the downloaded image that has no data at all. [Here is what it looks like when I open it in QGIS](https://imgur.com/a/wsXyTOJ)